# Substituting two different names with one name based on unique value using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am beginner in sql, and I have a problem in getting what I need.
I have a table includes brand names of different drugs (a drug could be a brand or any generic equivalent). I want to indicate for drug by one name instead of having to different names. The table like the follow:

```
Brand name              CN 
Lisinopril               5
Metaformin Hcl           6
Nexuim                   7
Tylenol                  8
Glucophage               6
Acetaminophen            8
```

The CN shows what to drugs are generically equivalent. The output I want is creating new column with one name only no matter which one for two equivalent products. The output as follow:

```
Brand name              CN 
Lisinopril               5
Metaformin Hcl           6
Nexuim                   7
Tylenol                  8
Metaformin Hcl           6
Tylenol                  8
```

The dataset I am using is very large and have multiple products

Comment: which one of the `Brand name` do you want to choose in the final output for which `CN` are same?

Comment: It doesn't matter which name, but it is better if I used the generic name because I have a third column its name is Brand with two values (0,1) so if I want the generic name, the Brand column should be 0 if I want the brand name so the Brand column should be 1

Comment: It doesn't matter what name?  You might be attempting to write code without knowing what it's supposed to do.  That's generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the window function `min()`:

```
select min(brand_name) over (partition by cn) as brand_name, cn
from table t;
```

This will assign the minimum `brand_name` for each `cn`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `subquery`:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName]
ADD [Custom Brand Name] [varchar](255)

UPDATE A
SET [Custom Brand Name] = (SELECT MIN([Brand Name]) FROM [TableName] WHERE CN = A.CN)
FROM [TableName] A
```